# Dialogflow integration with teams - Extract user information

Tags: dialogflow-es, microsoft-teams, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

We are trying to integrate Dialogflow chatbot with Microsoft Teams. We followed this tutorial https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/tree/master/skype
We got to a point where we’re able to send text-based basic intent mapped questions, and they’re working flawlessly.

Is there a way to extract user information out of Teams?

For example, in the Welcome Intent, instead of bot saying “Hello user”, is there a way to make it say “Hello John”?

A little bit of research led us to this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/issues/37#issuecomment-647927403 but we find it a little bit confusing. Are we supposed to develop a method to handle incoming requests within dialoglow-integration/server.js? If so, where should we look for the said user information? Any pointers will help.

TIA.

Comment: You can get user name by calling this method.




`public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
var userName = turnContext.Activity.From.Name;
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Welcome - {userName }");
}`

Comment: Please let us know does that help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the Answer for better knowledge

Copying from @Sridevi comments

You can get user name by calling this method.

```
public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) 
{
 var userName = turnContext.Activity.From.Name; await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Welcome - {userName }");

}
```

Comment: I believe the above piece of code is in C#. I am very new to this. May I please get some help in adding this piece of code (in node js) in [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/blob/master/skype/server.js).